# VBA Referring to named range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just starting to used named references within my VBA, but have hit a minor problem.

I have a named reference called "SiteCount" that counts the number of sites in a column

```
=COUNTA(Data!$B:$B)
```

It is saved as Workbook in scope and works when I use it in a cell as

```
=SiteCount
```

I thought I could use this in my code rather than replicate the calculation, however I can not save the value even just as

```
Sitecount = Range("SiteCount")
```

I have tried using the worksheet name as well, but I get the same 1004 "Method range of object global failed"

I'm guessing it's something very simple. but I can't figure it out.
Advice is gratefully received :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluate() should do since it's a formula name not a named range

```
Dim siteCount as Long
siteCount = Evaluate("SiteCount")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a named range, it's a named formula, so you have to refer to it differently. You can use:

```
lSiteCount = [SiteCount]
```

note that the variable name must not be the same as the formula name!

or

```
SiteCount = Sheets("Data").Evaluate("SiteCount")
```

or

```
SiteCount = Application.Evaluate("SiteCount")
```

Comment: Do not write `SiteCount = [SiteCount]` because when using `[...]`, it will first look in the VBA environment if a variable has the same name. So `[SiteCount]` will actually refer to the variable `SiteCount` if it is defined. `Evaluate` doesn't have that problem

Comment: Good point - that will teach me to add the variable part in after testing! I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the values of specific **named formulas** then:

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
    For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If n.Name = "SiteCount" Then
            MsgBox n.Value & vbCrLf & Evaluate(n.Value)
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```